# How to get an array of column values based on multiple INDEX and MATCH matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do you concatenate all values that match two criteria.

This is my data:[image]

And I would like to create a summary table that I was hoping it would look like this:
[image]

My current formula (I have tried for hours), looks like this `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(K1:O1=R2,VLOOKUP(Q3,J2:O5,MATCH(R2,K1:O1,0),FALSE),""))`

but its doing something else entirely. I think I may have overcomplicated it :/. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R3`:

`=LET(α,Q3:Q6,β,R2:T2,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(α),COLUMNS(β),LAMBDA(ξ,ζ,TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(K1:O1&"|"&J2:J5=INDEX(β,ζ)&"|"&INDEX(α,ξ),T(+K2:O5),"")))))`

This assumes that the entries in the source table are text, not numeric, just as in the example you give.

Comment: Amazing! I don't understand most of the formula - but thank you so much! I've spent hours trying to figure it out

Comment: Glad to help! If it helps, the *non-spill* version of the formula would be `TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(($K$1:$O$1=R$2)*($J$2:$J$5=$Q3),T(+$K$2:$O$5),""))`, which would then have to be dragged to the other required cells. The `MAKEARRAY`/`LAMBDA` construction just allows this to be auto-spilled, though perhaps this non-spill version helps you dissect more easily.

Comment: Thank you! I've got a few tables/files to manipulate - This is really helpful!